# Printing charts in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, chart.js

I am using Chart JS to render charts and using the below code to print them

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write("<br><img src='" + canvas.toDataURL() + "'/>");
    win.print();
    win.location.reload();
```

The code is working fine in IE but when I try to print in Chrome it is printing a blank page. Can someone please have a look and let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks